# How do I solve index alias error if I can't run elasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

The es instance I'm working with crashed, and attempting to restart the kernel leads to the run command immediately being killed (runES.sh: line 1: 92654 Killed ./bin/Elasticsearch).

The log shows this error:

```
[2022-03-02T10:40:54,802][INFO ][o.e.x.i.IndexLifecycleRunner] [smartmedia] policy [logstash-policy] for index [logstash-testin
dex] on an error step due to a transitive error, moving back to the failed step [check-rollover-ready] for execution. retry att
empt [24812]
[2022-03-02T10:50:54,779][ERROR][o.e.x.i.IndexLifecycleRunner] [smartmedia] policy [logstash-policy] for index [logstash-testin
dex] failed on step [{"phase":"hot","action":"rollover","name":"check-rollover-ready"}]. Moving to ERROR step
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [logstash] does not point to index [logstash-testindex]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ilm.WaitForRolloverReadyStep.evaluateCondition(WaitForRolloverReadyStep.java:104) [x-pa
ck-core-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ilm.IndexLifecycleRunner.runPeriodicStep(IndexLifecycleRunner.java:173) [x-pack-ilm-7.8.1.ja
r:7.8.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ilm.IndexLifecycleService.triggerPolicies(IndexLifecycleService.java:329) [x-pack-ilm-7.8.1.
jar:7.8.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ilm.IndexLifecycleService.triggered(IndexLifecycleService.java:267) [x-pack-ilm-7.8.1.jar:7.
8.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.scheduler.SchedulerEngine.notifyListeners(SchedulerEngine.java:183) [x-pack-core-7.8.1.
jar:7.8.1]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.scheduler.SchedulerEngine$ActiveSchedule.run(SchedulerEngine.java:211) [x-pack-core-7.8
.1.jar:7.8.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
```

If I understand correctly, the problem is this part: [logstash] does not point to index [logstash-testindex]. However I do not know how to change an alias for an index if I can't even start the kernel. This

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/logstash?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "aliases": {
    "logstash-testindex":{
      "is_write_index": true 
    }
  }
}
'
```

results in an error because elasticSearch is not actually running. Is there a config file I need to change instead?

Comment: do you have configured any template in logstash ?

Comment: what is version of ES ?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to below reason as mentioned in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-error-handling.html#_index_lifecycle_rollover_alias_x_does_not_point_to_index_y) document.

> Either the index is using the wrong alias or the alias does not exist.

If you are using ES version below 7.8 then you can set below [configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/ilm-settings.html#_cluster_level_settings) in elasticsearch.yml file.

```
xpack.ilm.enabled: false
```

Comment: I'm using 7.8.1. setting this configuration may have solved the ILM error, however elasticSearch is still immediately crashing when I try to run it:

esStack/elasticsearch-7.8.1$ ./bin/elasticsearch
[0.002s][warning][logging] Output options for existing outputs are ignored.
Killed

Comment: what log its generated ? can you enable debug log and check?

Comment: The only thing in the log file is what I have above, just repeated. Trying to run it now produces a gc.log file that reads: [2022-03-09T15:03:05.210+0000][116158][gc,heap] Heap region size: 2M
[2022-03-09T15:03:05.210+0000][116158][gc,heap,coops] Heap address: 0x0000000700000000, size: 4096 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3